# Koala Facebook App Access Token strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, access-token, koala

Hello everyone I've got some problems with Facebook lately. I have the following code:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController


before_filter :fb_auth

  def index    
    my_fql_query = 'SELECT eid, name, pic_cover,start_time, end_time, location, description,venue  FROM event 
    WHERE eid in(SELECT eid FROM event_member 
    WHERE uid IN (SELECT page_id FROM place 
    WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, "47.81", "13.04") < 1000)) ORDER BY start_time desc'

@rest = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@oauth.get_app_access_token)
@data = @rest.fql_query(my_fql_query) # convenience method

@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@data) do |data, marker|
  marker.lat data["venue"]["latitude"]
  marker.lng data["venue"]["longitude"]
  marker.content data["name"]
end


 end

  def fb_auth
    app_id = 'my id'
    app_secret = 'my secret'

@oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(app_id, app_secret)


end
```

It lists all Events from Facebook around a specific place and creates on google the markers.

Everything worked fine until the last few days. Then I called @oauth.get_app_access_token_info and it returned some strange access key.

{"access_token"=>"635332713179979|wijp_7qZJ_hdjHPl_UOMquTliMI"}

And it can't call any events. I hope you can help me out with this one. I posted the Access Token because it only shows me the name of the App on the debugger even though I specified some special permissions

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved. Don't know why but it works now.

Comment: `Koala::Facebook::API.new( @oauth.get_app_access_token )` saved my day.